# AngularJs AngularStrap bs-DatePicker returns undefined on ngModel

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-strap

I have a problem when I try to recieve the value from ngModel in my controller. The ngModel works since it sends the value to my input when the page loads, but when I change the input value the ngModel variable turns undefined.

#### Html code

```
<input ondrop="return false" maxlength="10" type="text" class="form-
control" date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" bs-datepicker ng-
model="vm.fechaInicio"  onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" 
oncopy="return false" placement="auto bottom" container="body" 
autoclose="true" />
```

#### Controller

```
  vm.especialidad = {};
  vm.fechaInicio = moment();
```

The version of AngularJS is v1.5.9 and angular-strap is v2.3.12

## Edit

I managed to work it out, the problem was that I used this in the controller and not $scope. Also I had to remove maxlength from the input.

Comment: Instead of editing your question with an answer, StackOverflow lets you answer your own question just like another user would. That is the preferred way, because it will show up in searches as an answered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Adrian Smith,
I managed to work it out, the problem was that I used "this" in the controller and not $scope. Also I had to remove maxlength from the input.